# Unexpected non-null value from mysql stored procedure call from mysqlconnector.net

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-connector

I ran into a surprise today, we are working on a application in C# that connects to a mysql database. Everything worked fine until today when we migrated some stuff from one server to another. Now, some data are missing in the database and the Stored Procedures were expected to return null values because of it. Unfortunately instead of null values for integers we get integer values of 0.

For simplicity lets say that I have the following stored procedure in our MySql Server:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `get_config_code`(
IN order_n BIGINT,
IN order_position_n INT,
OUT out_config_code BIGINT)
BEGIN
    set out_config_code = null;
END
```

then I call the stored procedure through MySqlConnector .net by creating a MySqlCommand instance adding the parameters to it. Then the stored procedure is called in a very straightforward way as follows:

```
mReader = mCommand.ExecuteReader();
if ((mReader != null) && (mReader .HasRows))
{
    mReader .Close();
}
```

then I try to check if the parameter is Null like this:

```
if (mCommand.Parameters[param_id].Value != System.DBNull.Value)
```

unfortunately despite the stored procedure explicitly setting the output parameter to null, the parameter is non null, and it is of type Int64 and has a value of 0 (checked it through the debugger)

The code works perfectly if data is actually there, and I get the correct integer value. My best guess is that it is not very easy to have a null "integer value" in c# as it is a non-nullable type... but I expected the parameter to be of type System.DBNull anyway, even for non-nullable types (it works perfectly for strings)

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance for any help

**UPDATE:** Well... we did some archeology on the testing of the system... it turns out that a null integer return from the stored procedure was never tested before, and that explains why problem did not arise earlier. We executed the stored procedure on the server before migration, with the same data in the DBs, and the 'problem' is there as well.

My understanding is that non-nullable data types are returned as their default, when the output parameter value is null; nullable data types are instead returned as expected as System.DBNull.Value when the output parameter is null.

What I found interesting is that, in case of int, the reader returned by the call to ExecuteReader, contains data which matching the value of the output parameter; when checking into the reader we found the expected null value, instead of the default value for int.

Comment: A different mySQL version possibly? [I found this bug documentation - the bug is that the out parameter returns null.](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=45060).  Beyond that, perhaps some universal configuration that can say, in effect, "if the out parameter is zero, return null".

Comment: @radarbob read the rather old bug, but the problem here is quite the opposite... I get a valued result instead of a null result

Comment: I was taking a guess that if "returning null is a bug" then perhaps that bug is fixed in a different version, now returning something-besides-null.  Did you change data providers / data provider versions?  Has the way `BIGINT` is handled/converted changed somehow? - see [System.Data.SqlTypes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.aspx)